# Excel VBS do Muliple this 1 after the other on same sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have a work book, that i need to create a button click for, that will get run evey month. I need it to do multiple procedures on the same sheet in a set order.

So far below this is the code i have that does all the function. i need some help in ordereing it in the correct way so that it runs following the list, and maybe tidying if up and little if you know of a beeter way to code it.

1. increase cell L3 value by 1
2. add 1 month to the dates in cells C7 & L7
3. copy cell N40 and paste value into N42
4. copy cell G36 and paste value into G37
5. copy cell G49 and paste value into G50
6. copy range N12:N27 and paste values into J12:J27
7. saveas "Payment `L3` `L7`.xlsm"

Here is the code I have so far.

```
    Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
         Dim mPay As Range
         Dim mTarget As Range
         Dim cisCurrent As Range
         Dim cisTarget As Range
         Dim taxCurrent As Range
         Dim taxTarget As Range
         Dim ttdCurrent As Range
         Dim ttdTarget As Range
         Dim TTD As String
    'Define the ranges
         Set ttdCurrent = ws.Range("N40")
          Set ttdTarget = ws.Range("N42")
         Set mPay = ws.Range("N12:N27")
          Set mTarget = ws.Range("J12:J27")
         Set cisCurrent = ws.Range("G36")
          Set cisTarget = ws.Range("G37")
         Set taxCurrent = ws.Range("G49")
          Set taxTarget = ws.Range("G50")
    'copy and paste special-add
         ttdCurrent.Copy
          ttdTarget.PasteSpecial xlValues
         ttdCurrent.Copy
          ttdTarget.PasteSpecial xlValues
         mPay.Copy
          mTarget.PasteSpecial xlValues
         cisCurrent.Copy
          cisTarget.PasteSpecial xlValues
         taxCurrent.Copy
          taxTarget.PasteSpecial xlValues
End Sub
```

I have managed to come up with some code that cowrk sof rchanging the date, increaseing L3 by 1 and saving the document.

Increase L3, and add 1 Month to Dates:

```
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()
Dim rDate As Range
Dim rDate2 As Range

Set rDate = ActiveSheet.Range("C7")
Set rDate2 = ActiveSheet.Range("L7")

With ActiveSheet
    Range("L3").Value = Range("L3").Value + 1
    rDate.Value = DateAdd("m", 1, rDate.Value)
        rDate.Value = DateSerial(Year(rDate), Month(rDate) + 1, 0)
    rDate2.Value = DateAdd("m", 1, rDate2.Value)
        rDate2.Value = DateSerial(Year(rDate), Month(rDate) + 1, 0)

End With
End Sub
```

This is the code for Saving AS:

```
Private Sub CommandButton6_Click()
Dim MyPath As String, MyRange As Range, MyDate As Range

MyPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path
Set MyDate = Sheets("SUB CON PAYMENT FORM").Range("L7")
Set MyRange = Sheets("SUB CON PAYMENT FORM").Range("L3") 'with the name of a cell
ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=MyPath & "\" & "Payment" & " " & MyRange.Value & " " & MyDate.Text & ".xlsm"
End Sub
```

Any help you can provide will be greatly appreciated!!!!

Comment: I see what you are trying to do, and I see your code, but I don't see a specific problem or where you are getting stuck.  Please update with a specific question

Comment: @gtwebb hi hopefully that makes a bit more sense.

Comment: So your question is, everything works well but I don't know how to order it?  I would tie each one to a button if they all need to be run.  In you command click just run 3 normal macros (adjust values, copy cells, save worksheet) which you have already written.

Comment: @gtwebb hi yes just not sure the best way to order it. Is there a better way to code it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking that are you asking a more professional and efficient way to code the code? If that was the case, perhaps I got few advises for you:

1. Use `Option Explicit` in your code . This to make sure you declare the object before using it.
2. Add `Application.ScreenUpdating =False` to enhance your macro performance.
3. The copy macro you substitute it by writing the formula in the cell if you are going to copy the value into the same cells. E.g. you can code the cell(N42) with the formula `=N40` to copy the value automatically whe the cell(N40) updated. Indirectly, you will reduce the declaration of variables in your code. Therefore the performance will be increased.
4. Normally, I will set the "pattern" : workbook.worksheet to a variable. E.g.

   ```
   Dim MyWorkbook As Workbook
   Dim MyWorksheet As Worksheet
   Set MyWorkbook = Workbooks("Book1.xlsm")
   Set MyWorksheet = WorkbookTemplate.Sheets("WorksheetName")
   ```

   than only use them in performing the transaction/tasks
5. Lastly, please use the meaningful variables to ease your future enhancement. If you are interesting to know more, you can read a book call "Clean Code"

Answer (score 0):

this is what i have come up with, hopefully i have done everything correct.

If you see a mistake or a better way of coding, then please let me know, i am always learning.

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
Dim aws As Worksheet
Dim MyPath As String, MyRange As Range, MyDate As Range
Dim rDate As Range, rDate2 As Range
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
        .CutCopyMode = False
    End With

Set aws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("SUB CON PAYMENT FORM")
Set MyRange = Sheets("SUB CON PAYMENT FORM").Range("L3")                    'Payment No
Set MyDate = Sheets("SUB CON PAYMENT FORM").Range("L7")                     'Date "MMMM YYYY"
Set rDate = ActiveSheet.Range("C7")
Set rDate2 = ActiveSheet.Range("L7")

MyPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Details").Rows(2 & ":" & Sheets("Details").Rows.Count).ClearContents 'This clears all data below the header in Details
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Global").Rows(1 & ":" & Sheets("Global").Rows.Count).ClearContents   'This clears all data below in Global

With ActiveSheet
    Range("L3").Value = Range("L3").Value + 1                               'Increases Payment No# by 1
        rDate.Value = DateSerial(Year(rDate), Month(rDate) + 1, Day(29))    'Increases Date by 1 Month
        rDate2.Value = DateSerial(Year(rDate), Month(rDate) + 1, 0)         'Increases Date by 1 Month
            With aws
            .Range("N40").Copy                                              'Copies total to date Value
            .Range("N42").PasteSpecial xlValues                             'Pastes total to date Value to Total Last Payment
                With aws
                .Range("G49").Copy                                          'Copies Total VAT to Date
                .Range("G50").PasteSpecial xlValues                         'Pastes Total VAT to Date into Last Payment
                .Range("G36").Copy                                          'Copies This Months Labour
                .Range("G37").PasteSpecial xlValues                         'Pastes This Months Laboue into Last Payment
                End With
                With aws
                .Range("N12:N27").Copy                                      'Copies CC Code Gross Value
                .Range("J12:J27").PasteSpecial xlValues                     'Pastes CC Code Gross Value into Previous
                End With
            End With
    Range("A1").Activate                                                    'Selects Cell A1
End With

ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=MyPath & "\" & "Payment" & " " & MyRange.Value & " " & MyDate.Text & ".xlsm" 'This saves a new document in our naming convention

End Sub
```